# Скрол меню на css

Tags: html, css

Есть такое меню, которое я планирую вставить на сайт как одно из подменю. На мобильных тач устройствах оно скролится, и можно нажать на любой элемент. На компе же скрола нет. Можно ли как то реализовать его, чтобы он скролился при наведении мыши слева и справа блока соответственно?
PS: в хроме показывает без полосы прокрутки (ее и не должно быть), а в фф с ней, тоже вопрос, как ее оттуда убрать?

```css
.her {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    background: red;
}
.herocarousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.heroprl {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    top: 1%;
    left: 1%;
    height: 98%;
    width: 98%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
}
.herocarousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.bord {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, grey 100%);
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    margin: 0 -8px 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 30px 50px 90px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
            box-shadow: inset 30px 50px 90px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
}
.bord:hover {
        transform: translate(0, 6px);
        /*-webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
        transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);*/

}
.heroallw {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.herow {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 14em;
    width: 28em;
}
.herow img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="her">
<div class="herocarousel">
    <div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div></div><div class="bord"><div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div></div>
</div><br>
<div id="hero1">
    <div class="heroh">Ringo</div>
    <div class="heroallw"><div class="herow"><img src="img/herosplashart/RingoW1.jpg"></div></div><br>
    <div class="herocont">text text text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно полезный ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820304/hidden-scrollbars-in-firefox-allows-scrolling-but-just-no-scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну... Как-то так :)

```js
let autoScroller = {
  offsetPercentage: .2, // это свойство показывает в каком процентном соотношении от границ начинать скроллить элемент
  mousePosition: { // текущее расположение мыши внутри элемента
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  scrollSpeed: .3, // скорость скролла
  scrollerElementSelector: '.herocarousel', // селектор элемента, на который надо скроллить
}

// определяет старт скролла. Подписывается на события hover и mousemove
autoScroller.startMonitor = function() {
  let _this = this;
  $(this.scrollerElementSelector).hover(
    function(e) {
      _this.hoverInEvent(e, _this);
    },
    function(e) {
      _this.hoverOutEvent(e, _this);
    });
  $(this.scrollerElementSelector).mousemove(function(e) {
    _this.mouseMove(e, _this);
  });
}
// просто обновляет значения расположение мыши внутри элемента
autoScroller.mouseMove = function(e, _this) {
  var elementOffset = $(e.currentTarget).offset();
  _this.mousePosition.x = e.pageX - elementOffset.left;
  _this.mousePosition.y = e.pageY - elementOffset.top;
}
// запускает интервал, в котором высчитывается и скроллится элемент
autoScroller.hoverInEvent = function(e, _this) {
  _this.monitorInterval = setInterval(function() {
    let width = $(e.currentTarget).width();
    let height = $(e.currentTarget).height();
    let horizontalOffset = _this.offsetPercentage * width;
    let verticalOffset = _this.offsetPercentage * height;
    
    // высчитываем силу скролла (чем ближе к краям - тем быстрее надо скроллить)
    let scrollPower = {
      x: _this.mousePosition.x - horizontalOffset,
      y: _this.mousePosition.y - verticalOffset
    };
    if (scrollPower.x > 0) {
      scrollPower.x = _this.mousePosition.x - width + horizontalOffset;
      if (scrollPower.x < 0) {
        scrollPower.x = 0;
      }
    }
    if (scrollPower.y > 0) {
      scrollPower.y = _this.mousePosition.y - height + verticalOffset;
      if (scrollPower.y < 0) {
        scrollPower.y = 0;
      }
    }
    // умножаем на scrollSpeed
    scrollPower.x *= _this.scrollSpeed;
    scrollPower.y *= _this.scrollSpeed;

    // применяем скролл
    e.currentTarget.scrollLeft += scrollPower.x;
    e.currentTarget.scrollTop += scrollPower.y;
  }, 25);
}
// удаляет интервал
autoScroller.hoverOutEvent = function(e, _this) {
  clearInterval(_this.monitorInterval);
  _this.monitorInterval = null;
}

// стартуем скролл
autoScroller.startMonitor();
```

```css
.her {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  background: red;
}

.herocarousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.heroprl {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  top: 1%;
  left: 1%;
  height: 98%;
  width: 98%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
}

.herocarousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.bord {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, grey 100%);
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 0 -8px 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 30px 50px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  box-shadow: inset 30px 50px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
}

.bord:hover {
  transform: translate(0, 6px);
  /*-webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
        transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);*/
}

.heroallw {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.herow {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 14em;
  width: 28em;
}

.herow img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="her">
  <div class="herocarousel">
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Adagio.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Alpha.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bord">
      <div class="heroprl"><img src="img/heroes/Ringo.jpg" width="100%"></div>
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <div id="hero1">
    <div class="heroh">Ringo</div>
    <div class="heroallw">
      <div class="herow"><img src="img/herosplashart/RingoW1.jpg"></div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="herocont">text text text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```